# TikTok Android SDK integration doesn't work

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, integration, tiktok

I'm trying to integrate TikTok sdk into Android app to be able to start marketing campaigns.

I follow this guide - https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/mobile-sdk-android-quickstart/
Looks like I'm doing something wrong

So, I've added into build.gradle (Project):

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/AwemeOpenSDK" }
}
```

I've also addet this into build.gradle (Module: app):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.tiktok.open.sdk:tiktok-open-sdk-core:2.0.2'
}
```

If I try to build my app it says that Android Studio can't download dependency from repository. There are 3 tries from 3 repos: Google, JCentral and Maven Central

Here is output:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.tiktok.open.sdk:tiktok-open-sdk-core:2.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/tiktok/open/sdk/tiktok-open-sdk-core/2.0.2/tiktok-open-sdk-core-2.0.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tiktok/open/sdk/tiktok-open-sdk-core/2.0.2/tiktok-open-sdk-core-2.0.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/tiktok/open/sdk/tiktok-open-sdk-core/2.0.2/tiktok-open-sdk-core-2.0.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

Also, I should mention: Android Studio is new for me, however I'm a developer in another domain. Maybe it's just my mistake

Anyone faced this problem before?
Thanks